# Security, Filter and Encoding

Tags: tomcat, encoding, url-parameters

i like to log url-parameters per request. I decided to use a servlet filter who is called before any servlet is called.

When i read the name of the parameters the parameters are (unfortunately) cached and the values of the parameters are cached too in a default charset.

This is a problem because i decide in the servlet what charset the request will have. But i can not change the charset to UTF8 when a previous read of the parameters has cached them to ISO-8859-1.

Any idea?

EDIT: Code

```
public final class XXX implements Filter {
  public void doFilter(final ServletRequest in, 
      final ServletResponse out, final FilterChain chain){
    in.getParameterMap();
    chain.doFilter(in,out);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? What is the charset of the request? See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1

Comment: `request.getCharacterEncoding()` sais `null`

Comment: "If a character encoding is not specified, the Servlet specification requires that an encoding of ISO-8859-1 is used." What is the actual encoding used by client(s) sending these requests?

Comment: @SameerNaik The client does not specify the encoding in the post-form! It should be specified by the header-value of `content-type` as you can see it in `org.apache.coyote.Request:313`. But the header for `content-type` is missing, so the encoding is `null`.